# How to compare two methods using selenium

Tags: selenium

Below are the two methods

```
gettablevalueprd("//div[@id='Catalog']//tr",2,"Large Angelfish",0,"EST-1");
gettablevalueshopcart("//div[@id='Catalog']//tr",2,"Large Angelfish",0,"EST-1");
```

Below is the first method

```
public static void gettablevalueprd(String xPath,int descriptionid,String expectvalue1,int itemid,String expectedvalue2) {
    //String xPath = "//div[@id='Catalog']//tr";
    List<WebElement> tableList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath));
    System.out.println("Item ID\t\tProduct ID\t\tDescription\t\tList Price\t\tButton");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for(int i=1;i<tableList.size();i++) {
        List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath+"["+(i+1)+"]/td"));
        for(int j=0;j<listData.size();j++) {

            System.out.print(listData.get(j).getText()+"\t\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // description is in the 3rd(2nd index) column so we can fetch that with the index number 2.
    for(int i=1;i<tableList.size();i++) {
        List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath+"["+(i+1)+"]/td"));
        if(listData.get(descriptionid).getText().trim().equals(expectvalue1)) {
            System.out.println("Description for Item ID is "+listData.get(descriptionid).getText());
        }
        if(listData.get(itemid).getText().trim().equals(expectedvalue2)) {
            System.out.println("Item ID is  "+listData.get(itemid).getText());
            //to click on add to cart button
            listData.get(4).click();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

*Another method is*

```
public static void gettablevalueshopcart(String xPath1,int descriptionid, String expectvalue1, int itemid, String expectedvalue2) {
         //String xPath1 = "//div[@id='Catalog']//tr";
            List<WebElement> shoppingtableList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath1));
            System.out.println("Item ID\t\tProduct ID\t\tDescription\t\tInstock\t\tList Price\tTotalcost\t\tButton");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            for(int i=1;i<shoppingtableList.size();i++) {
                List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath1+"["+(i+1)+"]/td"));
                for(int j=0;j<listData.size();j++) {

                    System.out.print(listData.get(j).getText()+"\t\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
         // description is in the 3rd(2nd index) column so we can fetch that with the index number 2.
            for(int i=1;i<shoppingtableList.size();i++) {
                List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath1+"["+(i+1)+"]/td"));
                if(listData.get(descriptionid).getText().trim().equals(expectvalue1)) {
                    System.out.println("Description for Item ID is "+listData.get(descriptionid).getText());
                }
                if(listData.get(itemid).getText().trim().equals(expectedvalue2)) {
                    System.out.println("Item ID is  "+listData.get(itemid).getText());
                break;
                }
            }
    }
```

**Here i want two compare two values from table **

Comment: Can you please describe, what you asked? I see two methods, but I don't understand you question.

Comment: I need to compare both values present inside two methods